# How to execute 'Zoom Fit' in ModelSim/QuestaSim from TCL console?

Tags: tcl, vhdl, simulator, modelsim

I'm using ModelSim / Questa-SIM from command line in GUI mode. If ModelSim runs in GUI mode I would like to execute a 'Zoom Fit' from my imported 'wave.do' file.

I pass this file to vsim by `-do wave.do`. Here is the script:

```
add wave *
run -all
```

I started vsim and saved a waveform window as `test.do`. This file contains statements like this:

```
WaveRestoreZoom {0 fs} {2724750 ps}
```

**Is it possible to calculate the upper boundary in TCL?**

I also found a `simtime` statement, but using simtime as a second parameter gives an error:

```
VSIM1> simtime
       # {5,195 ns} {1       } /arith_counter_gray_tb 0 0
VSIM1> WaveRestoreZoom {0 fs} {simetime}
       # zoomrange: invalid range "0 fs simetime"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, `wave zoom full` works for me.

Your technique works if you use `WaveRestoreZoom {0 fs} [simtime]`. By putting `simtime` in curly braces, you're asking for it to be treated as a literal string. Square brackets ask it to try to evaluate the expression within. You could equally use `WaveRestoreZoom {0 fs} [eval simtime]`.

Comment: oOo, `wave zoom ...` that's to easy :)